# How does copy from nearby device from Nexus 5x to Nexus 6p work?

Tags: backup, sync, google-account, 7.0-nougat, nexus-6p

I recently got my new Nexus 6p and used that procedure (copy from another nearby device) to copy data from my existing Nexus 5x to it:

http://phoneradar.com/how-to-transfer-data-to-a-new-android-phone-with-set-up-nearby-device-feature/

However, when I got to the point where I needed to compare the two codes, I accidentally clicked on Next, without comparing them. However, everything got synced on Nexus 6p in about 10 seconds, my desktop instantly looked exactly the same (with the applications starting to install).

It got me thinking - how does the procedure work? I couldn't find info on it.

- Are Bluetooth/WiFi only needed for discovery, is any data transmitted over them?
- Is data kept on Google servers so that when the phones approve they are nearby there is an unique ID (or shared keys) that allow copying of account data to this exact device (Nexus 6p) from the servers to it?
- Is it possible that if the codes were different and I clicked Next and if there is a man in the middle - could he/she receive the account info and at the same time I see it intact on my new Nexus 6p?

In general, I would be grateful if somebody could explain the procedure.

Thanks.